# Too few arguments to function WP_Widget::__construct(),

Tags: widgets

first time with custom widget. I'm trying to create it this way:

```
<?php
namespace App;

class My_Widget extends \WP_Widget {
    function My_Widget() {

        $widget_ops = [
            'name' => 'My widget',
            'description' => 'My description'
        ];
        parent::__construct( 'My_Widget', 'My widget', $widget_ops );
    }
}

function load_widget() {
    register_widget( 'App\\my_widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\load_widget' );
```

And I get this error:

```
Too few arguments to function WP_Widget::__construct(), 0 passed in /srv/www/contraindicaciones.net/current/web/wp/wp-includes/class-wp-widget-factory.php on line 61 and at least 2 expected
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You're using an extremely outdated method of creating a widget. You should be using the `__construct()` function, not a named function, as the constructor, [as documented](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/functionality/widgets/#example-with-a-namespace).

```
namespace App;

class My_Widget extends \WP_Widget {
    function __construct() {

        $widget_ops = [
            'name' => 'My widget',
            'description' => 'My description'
        ];
        parent::__construct( 'My_Widget', 'My widget', $widget_ops );
    }
}

function load_widget() {
    register_widget( 'App\\my_widget' );
}
add_action( 'widgets_init', __NAMESPACE__ . '\\load_widget' );
```

Comment: Thanks! It works. Here in the codex remain the old method as an example: https://codex.wordpress.org/es:API_de_Widget#Desarrollando_Widgets.

Comment: Unfortunately it looks like the Spanish documentation on the codex is extremely out of date. Use developer.wordpress.org if you can (I couldn't figure out how to check if there's decent Spanish translations).

Comment: This is fantastic and resolved my setup- now up and running on PHP8.  Many thanks!