# WordPress PHP8.2 Critical Error in class-wp-widget.php

Tags: php, widgets

Recently updated to PHP8.2 and I'm getting a critical error related to the theme.

The critical error is:

Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function WP_Widget::__construct(), 0 passed in /home/klm/ftp/hpt/wp-includes/class-wp-widget-factory.php on line 62 and at least 2 expected in /home/klm/ftp/hpt/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php:163 Stack trace: #0 /home/klm/ftp/hpt/wp-includes/class-wp-widget-factory.php(62): WP_Widget->__construct() #1 /home/klm/ftp/hpt/wp-includes/widgets.php(115): WP_Widget_Factory->register('qns_booking_wid...') #2 /home/klm/ftp/hpt/wp-content/themes/nice_hotel/functions/widgets/widget-booking.php(138): register_widget('qns_booking_wid...') #3 /home/klm/ftp/hpt/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): qns_booking_widget('') #4 /home/klm/ftp/hpt/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #5 /home/klm/ftp/hpt/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #6 /home/klm/ftp/hpt/wp-includes/widgets.php(1858): do_action('widgets_init') #7 /home/klm/ftp/hpt/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): wp_widgets_init('') #8 /home/klm/ftp/hpt/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters(NULL, Array) #9 /home/klm/ftp/hpt/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array) #10 /home/klm/ftp/hpt/wp-settings.php(643): do_action('init') #11 /home/klm/ftp/hpt/wp-config.php(103): require_once('/home/klm/ftp/h...') #12 /home/klm/ftp/hpt/wp-load.php(50): require_once('/home/klm/ftp/h...') #13 /home/klm/ftp/hpt/wp-admin/admin.php(34): require_once('/home/klm/ftp/h...') #14 /home/klm/ftp/hpt/wp-admin/index.php(10): require_once('/home/klm/ftp/h...') #15 {main} thrown in /home/klm/ftp/hpt/wp-includes/class-wp-widget.php on line 163

Please help to fix this problem

Comment: this is usually caused by a widget that wasn't built correctly, the stack trace points the finger at `themes/nice_hotel/functions/widgets/widget-booking.php` and a widget that begins with `qns_booking_wid`, is this code you wrote yourself? Or is `nice_hotel` a theme you bought/downloaded?

Answer (score 2):

Seems like the theme you use (nice_hotel?) uses an extremely outdated version of registering a widget (see [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/383777/too-few-arguments-to-function-wp-widget-construct)). As this seems to be a premium theme, you should probably contact the themes author, but as i couldn't find an "active" version of this theme (if it is nice_hotel: themeforest theme shows "no longer available"), you're probably going to get into more trouble along the way. You should probably switch the theme or pay a developer to make the theme PHP8- / Wordpress6-Compatible.

Happy Coding!

Comment: There's [a contact form for the author on themeforest](https://themeforest.net/user/quitenicestuff) you could try too.

Comment: @Rup if you've identified it's a question asking about a 3rd party product you should vote to close the question as offtopic